# MySQL - Select Domains from url only

Tags: mysql

Can someone explain what the FOR is doing in this query as I have never seen this usage before in MySQL

```
SELECT SUBSTR( 
    url FROM 1 FOR IF( LOCATE('/', url, 9)!= 0, LOCATE('/', url, 9) - 1, LENGTH(url)  ) 
) AS justurl FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Are you sure this is MySQL? Best I can find is a `LOOP` for MySQL, no `FOR` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/loop.html

Comment: Yep, this actually works, just don't understand how.

Answer (score 0):

A Colleague pointed out where I was going wrong, I was missing the fact that SUBSTR allows you to write FROM and FOR inside it. Dam these 4GL languages.

```
SUBSTR(str FROM pos FOR len)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr